How to filter a query with a parameter only if it's passed?
I dont want to write two statements like this
if(filter_by_company) {
  query..
} else {
  query...
}

So select users and they are in companies and I the admin can filter like by company id. How can I say when filter not exists then dont make the condition ?
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN clients c
ON c.id = u.company_id
WHERE c.company_id = 'NAME' IF EXISTS ?? ELSE DONT ASK

how can I do it ?

This would be easier to understand if you provided basic schemas for users and clients, sample data, and your expected results in your two different situations.

Is company_id really the primary key of clients, and it's the client name?

What I think you're asking is how do you write one query which can handle both filtering by company, and not filtering by company.
SELECT * 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN clients c
ON c.id = u.company_id
WHERE c.company_id = 'NAME'

and
SELECT * 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN clients c
ON c.id = u.company_id

There's two approaches. First is to try to construct this as one query. The second is to use a more flexible approach to building queries.

To do it in one query, you'd pass in a boolean flag to determine whether or not to filter by company.
SELECT * 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN clients c
ON c.id = u.company_id
WHERE (:any_company or c.id = :company_id)

Demonstration.
This is acceptable for something simple, but this technique is very limited and leads to unnecessarily complex queries.

Far better is to use a SQL query builder to build up your queries. Then you can write a generic query and add clauses onto it. What you use depends on your choice of programming languages, for these examples we'll use Knex.js.
First, build the basic query.
const user_client_query = knex
  .select('*')
  .from('users')
  .leftJoin('clients', 'users.company_id', 'clients.id');

And add to it as needed.
const filter_user_by_client = user_client_query.where('clients.company_id', 'ConHuge Corp')

filter_user_by_client is a new object, user_client_query is unaffected.
The beauty of this technique is you can add limits, orders, more where clauses, more joins, and so on.
user_client_query.orderBy('user.last_login').limit(10)

And it will adapt to SQL dialects for you.

You could also use (:company_id IS NULL or c.id = :company_id)

@FrankHeikens See my answer..

Assuming you are passing company_id as a positional parameter, pass it twice in succession (pass null in your programming language when you don't filter_by_company):
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN clients c
ON c.id = u.company_id
WHERE (? IS NULL OR c.company_id = ?);

If your client allows named parameters, you can use:
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN clients c
ON c.id = u.company_id
WHERE (:company_id IS NULL OR c.company_id = :company_id);

or some other equivalent parameter syntax.

Though technically possible this leads to poor SQL performance. Dynamic SQL performs much better, though it requires more coding.

I highly doubt that a short-circuiting NULL IS NULL check leads to any kind of significant performance impact.

The answer is correct, but it will generate a less than optimal plan, and that could be of interest to the OP. If NULL IS NULL is hardcoded in literal form, I would agree with you. However, if the expression is parameterized as ? IS NULL, then that's a totally different animal.

try this
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN clients c ON c.id = u.company_id
WHERE (:filter_by_company = 0 OR c.company_id = :company_id)


Exactly how is this an answer? What is :filter_by_company supposed to represent?

@AdrianKlaver :filter_by_company is a boolean parameter (0 for false, 1 for true).

select 0 =0; t which means :filter_by_company = 0 is going to select everything. Provide a working example of what you are propsoing.

@AdrianKlaver: Yes, that’s the point. Select everything if not filtering by company.

@Ry-, yeah I reversed the logic in my head, my mistake.
